# How to customize a theme for css properties for which SASS variables are not given extjs 4

Tags: css, extjs, sass, theming

I have created a custom theme which extends the Neptune theme provided by Sencha by reading out the this [theming tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/theming) . Now the as i have read from the tutorial and from various other sources you can customize your theme by using the mixins and css Variables of each component provided in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#).

The issue which i am facing is that what is needed to be done in case i need to customize a css property for which a SASS variable doesn't exist and how & should i add that code if i do use the css directly.

For an example i am using a textfield using this custom theme i created and i want to add the transition css property to it along with other form field focus property but the only focus property using sass variable from the list is **$form-field-focus-border-color**

[image]

I read many forums and got this as one of the solutions

--->It said that i need to enter the css code for that component directly in the sass file **scss/var/form/** folder inside the theme package and i did find out that class from browser inspection tool and after adding it it worked. Below is the code for base.scss file in above mentioned path

```
$form-field-height: 24px !default;
$form-toolbar-field-height: $form-field-height !default;
$form-field-padding: 4px 6px 3px !default;
$form-field-border-color: #c0c0c0 #d9d9d9 #d9d9d9 !default;
$form-field-border-width: 1px !default;
$form-field-invalid-border-color: red !default;
/**
 * @var {color} $form-field-focus-border-color
 * In the default neptune color scheme this is the same as $base-highlight-color
 * but it does not change automatically when one changes the $base-color.  This is because
 * checkboxes and radio buttons have this focus color hard coded into their background
 * images.  If this color is changed, you should also modify checkbox and radio button
 * background images to match
 */
$form-field-focus-border-color: mix(#fff, #157fcc, 15%) !default;
$form-field-background-image: null !default;
$form-field-invalid-background-image: null !default;

.x-form-text {
   transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

But i am not sure whether it is the correct way.

Is this the way all the customization css should be added to theme ?

Where can i find sass variables for all the css properties that i need for customization and if they aren't available how should i style all the other css properties for a component ?